# Как работает <? extends SomeClass> в Map<K,V>?

Tags: java, map

Есть два класса **EJPlayer** (Интерфейс) и **EPlayer** (Дочерний)

Есть массив `ConcurrentHashMap<String,? extends EJPlayer>`

По логике EPlayer же должен помещаться в этот массив? По итогу ошибка в методе put(k,v)

Код:

```
public class EPlayer implements EJPlayer {

    protected static ConcurrentHashMap<String,? extends EJPlayer> registeredEPlayers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static EJPlayer registerEPlayer(Player p) {
        return EPlayer.registeredEPlayers.put(p.getName(), new EPlayer(p)); // Ошибка тут
    }

    public static EJPlayer getEPlayer(Player p) {
        if (EPlayer.registeredEPlayers.containsKey(p.getName()))
            return EPlayer.registeredEPlayers.get(p.getName());
        else
            return EPlayer.registerEPlayer(p);
    }
}
```

Класс EJPlayer (Методы указанные тут есть в EPlayer)

```
public interface EJPlayer {

    public Player getPlayer();

    public ReadOnlySettings getSettings();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как решить вашу проблему:**

Конкретно ваша задача решается использованием базового типа в рамках generic'а вместо wildcard, как вы и описали выше:

```
protected static ConcurrentMap<String, EJPlayer> registeredEPlayers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

---

**Рекомендации:**

- В Java принято работать с интерфейсами, а не с их реализацией, именно поэтому, в блоке кода, приведенном мною выше, в качестве типа переменной используется `ConcurrentMap` (возможно, вам даже будет достаточно и просто интерфейса `Map`), а не `ConcurrentHashMap`.
- Если ваше статическое поле с `Map`'ой, потенциально, не должно никогда переприсваиваться, то лучше сразу объявите его как `final` (тогда по рекомендациям и переменную назовете в верхнем регистре, т.к. она станет `static final`).

---

**Про wildcard generics:**

Вопрос же касательно wildcard generic'ов, на самом деле, совсем нетривиальный.
Если вкратце, то существует принцип `The Get and Put Principle`, он же `PECS` (`Producer Extends Consumer Super`)):

- Если объявить wildcard с использованием `extends`, то это producer. Он только предоставляет элемент из контейнера, а сам ничего не принимает (за исключением `null`).
- Если же объявить wildcard с использованием `super`, то это consumer. Он только принимает, а предоставить ничего не может (за исключением `Object`).

Подробнее с этой особенностью wildcard generic в Java можете ознакомиться [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) и [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/sberbank/blog/416413/).

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, теперь всё понял)

Answer (score 1):

Поменял `<String,? extends EJPlayer>` на `<String,EJPlayer>` и всё заработало.. Извиняюсь за флуд в ленте)